# Ошибка, функция Loc, Too many indexers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

На примере игрушечного датафрейма df:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне надо в столбцах В и С построчно найти минимальные значения.
`df.loc[:,'B':'C'].min(axis=1)`
При такой записи все работает корректно, но если это запихнуть в apply:
`df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[:,'B':'C'].min(axis=1),axis=1)`
то возникает ошибка: Too many indexers

Comment: можете объяснить зачем красивый и понятный код `df.loc[:,'B':'C'].min(axis=1)` заменять неуклюжим монстром `df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[:,'B':'C'].min(axis=1),axis=1)` ??

Comment: Ну раз задаю, значит нужен. У меня большой датасет, где надо построчно найти минимальные значения из диапазона колонок, и потом с этими значениями проводится еще куча операций. Можно конечно делать первым способом, создавать колонки на каждой операции и потом удалять промежуточные. Но хочется взять строку, совершить все операции и получить готовый ответ для этой строки.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вы изобретаете велосипед. Вы расширить свой вопрос до исходной вашей проблемы и примером оригинального датасета? Возможно, эту проблему можно решить намного более простым способом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

слегка подправил ваш код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80]], columns=list('abcd'))

print(df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[['b','c']].min(), axis=1))
```

вывод:

```
0    20
1    60
dtype: int64
```

Comment: В принципе да, заранее составить список имен колонок и передавать уже его.